# how to handle token authentication in Angular Dart?

Tags: django-rest-framework, dart, local-storage, token, django-rest-auth

First time dealing with a SPA. I have a back-end restful service that returns a token when a user signs in. I know I am supposed to send the token through the headers in each request so I was thinking in saving the token in a file and create a service or a class that loads the token in every component but I don't know if this is a good approach as I can't find documentation for Angular Dart about this.

Comment: You can save the token in localStorage

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint. Saving it to localStorage was very efficient, I can access to the token key as I planned. I still can't set the authorization in the header. I get a 401 error from the server if I set it to headers: {"Authorization": "Token "+token_key}

Comment: That depends on what the server expects exactly.  What server are you accessing? "I can't find documentation for Angular Dart", this isn't related to Angular and doesn't need any special Angular support.

Comment: I'm using a local server with django and it's configuration was the problem. I solved it by adding a configuration ('rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',) that wasn't in the documentation of the library (django-rest-auth) And yeah, I see now that it's not related to Angular Dart.

Answer (score 1):

I saved the Token first in localStorage as Tobe O suggested:

```
Future login(username, password) async {
    String url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/login/';
    var response =
    await _client.post(url, body: {'username': username, 'password': password});
    Map mapped_response = _decoder.convert(response.body);
    window.localStorage.addAll({"token": mapped_response["key"]});
}
```

But still I was receiving 401 responses when I tried to get user information, this was the function:

```
  Future check_authentification () async {
      String _headers_key = "Authorization";
      String _headers_value =  "Token "+window.localStorage["token"];
      var response = await _client.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/user/", headers: {_headers_key: _headers_value});
      user_data = _decoder.convert(response.body);
      response_status = response.statusCode;
  }
```

I couldn't get authorized because django-rest-auth wasn't properly configured for token authorization. The solution was to add TokenAuthentication to the default authentication classes in django settings.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
)}
```